# Is it possible to have an unbound class member in Python?

Tags: python

Hopefully I asked this question correctly.  I have the code example:

```
class myc:
    a = ['a', 'b']

    def f1(self):
        b = myc.a
        b.extend(['c', 'd'])
        return b

    def f2(self):
        b = myc.a
        b.extend(['f','g'])
        return b


cvar = myc()

print cvar.f1()
print cvar.f2()
print cvar.f1()
```

I get the output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'c', 'd']
```

What I want is for "a" to be static.

My understanding is that because of "binding", when I do "b = myc.a" and I then do "b.extend...", I am actually affecting myc.a.

What I want is to make a copy of myc.a and store it in b so that my operations on b, don't affect myc.a.

I am obviously missing some basic Python concept here beyond binding.

The output I want is:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'f', 'g']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: I think you'll find this helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Here's a video version of @PM-2Ring's link: [link](https://youtu.be/_AEJHKGk9ns)

Comment: I guess this came down less to a variable/binding problem and more of an issue related to lists.  Looks like you clone it by either:  v = x[:] or more preferably v = list(x)